# Relevance of OneDrive SDK for Python

Tags: python, onedrive

I just had a concern regarding the relevance of the OneDrive SDK for Python maintained at https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python. 
Last commit was more than two years ago. Just wondering if this Python API will still work or nothing has changed in the OneDrive world to warrant an api update since the last commit?

Can someone please suggest if this API is actively maintained?

An email with same question to opencode@microsoft.com is still unanswered.

Comment: “Last commit more than 2 years ago” => as you can see, this particular Python API is not actively maintained. It doesn’t mean it won’t work though. Does it work for you?

Comment: The OneDrive API is part of Microsoft Graph - on this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/?view=odsp-graph-online someone from Microsoft commented on an issue in November 2018 so I would say it's not completely dead...

Comment: May be not, but if I spend 10 minutes developing an app which is gonna be dead an hour later, it will be a huge waste of my time. I know tech moves fast and I don't need all lights to be green to move my car, just need to know if I am gonna hit a dead end or a well maintained road.

Comment: Still no new commits 3+ years later..