# Is onedrive-sdk-python API still alive?

Tags: python, api, github, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

The author from `python-onedrive` [python-onedrive](https://github.com/mk-fg/python-onedrive) **warns** that his library is achrived and obsoleted by official library from microsoft and refers to its git repo [sdk](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-python)

What perplexes me is that the *archived obsoleted* library is being maintained while the official repo is dead since 6 years ago. What's going on?

Thanks.

Comment: question is asked here with no answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55156200/relevance-of-onedrive-sdk-for-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears the project was written before Microsoft authored their own SDK that solves the goal the creator originally had - namely that there was no Python SDK for OneDrive. Looking at the [commit history](https://github.com/mk-fg/python-onedrive/commits/master), there's been no meaningful changes in six years. The only changes were typos in the documentation, which was cleaned up for long-term archival purposes.

The author probably came to the conclusion that it's not worth maintaining a parallel SDK when an official one exists, which in theory should be maintained by the owner of OneDrive. Now, as to why Microsoft has not updated that SDK in six years is another issue entirely. There have been pull requests made to improve that library, but it's likely someone responsible for maintaining the repo needs to be contacted.

Comment: If you are in my place, and want to get work done against this funny backdrop, which api would you go with?

Comment: I would personally be wary of any SDK that hasn't been maintained in half a decade. It may work, but there are certainly security concerns and other additional costs associated with that. You may want to explore making the calls directly yourself, depending on the complexity of your needs.

That said, choosing between the two repos, one has been deprecated and archived in favor of an officially supported repo.

Answer (score 2):

The `python-onedrive` library was depreciated in 2015 [in this commit](https://github.com/mk-fg/python-onedrive/commit/91203a8daf29bf9c2254f7a6f16cf67b496237be).

The [commits from July 2021](https://github.com/mk-fg/python-onedrive/commit/d46fc9f32d72104d060914c096db19755a8c7ca7) are typo fixes, which is why it appears to be actively maintained.